# .net Saving Very Large Images

Tags: .net, image, bitmap, jpeg

I'm creating some very large images in .net and i'm using JPEG compression to get the file size down. However, if the image exceeds 65,000(ish) pixels in either width or height, I can no longer use jpeg compression. Is there a max dimensions limit for JPEG?

the exception being thrown is:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException (0x80004005): A generic error occurred in GDI+.
   at System.Drawing.Image.Save(String filename, ImageCodecInfo encoder, EncoderParameters encoderParams)

the code that is saving the image:

```
public static void SaveImage(ref Bitmap b, string fName)
    {
        long quailty = 75;
        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = getEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        Encoder myEncoder = Encoder.Quality;
        using (EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1))
        {
            using (EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new EncoderParameter(myEncoder, quailty))
            {
                myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
                b.Save(fName, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
            }
        }
    }
```

in the case of the above exception the image is 2,000x100,000 the magic number seems to be in the 65k range, both width and height.  Like, I can do 4,000x55,000 but not 2x70000.

I've also tried using a BitmapWriter, with the code below, and i get the error: "The image dimensions are out of the range supported by this codec"

```
wb = new WriteableBitmap(2000, 100000, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Bgra32,    null);

using (FileStream stream5 = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
PngBitmapEncoder encoder5 = new PngBitmapEncoder();
encoder5.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(wb));
encoder5.Save(stream5);
}
```

Comment: Hello.  I've tried that, with WritableBitmap and run into the same problem.  Raw saves fine, jpeg throw the exception.

Comment: post updated above

Comment: Wikipedia says the maximum size for a jpeg is 65535 pixels in either dimension.  You seem to be right up against the limit.

Comment: The width and height values in the JPEG file header are stored as 16-bit unsigned integers. The maximum value for an unsigned int is 65535. If you really need JPEG compression, you can put JPEG data in a TIFF file container and it stores the width/height as 32-bit integers so it would allow for larger images.

Comment: Thanks BitBank, any resources to share on how to do that?